# How to configure Logging levels in lumen

Tags: php, laravel, logging, lumen

After Seraching on web I get some detail from https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#configuration

```
Log::emergency($error);
Log::alert($error);
Log::critical($error);
Log::error($error);
Log::warning($error);
Log::notice($error);
Log::info($error);
Log::debug($error);
```

Now For example I want to setup Only alert,emergency and info levels only to be config .How to do this .Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that. But you can extend your `App\Exceptions\Handler` class to change your application's behavior when reporting an error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

In the [Official Documentation](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#configuration), u can have a straight forward way.

### Easy Config-

1. Create a .env file
2. Add `APP_DEBUG=true` in that file

U are Done !!!!

If you would like to have complete control over how Monolog is configured for your application, you may use the application's configureMonologUsing method.

### Custom Monolog Configuration-

You should place a call to this method in your `bootstrap/app.php` file:

```
    $app->configureMonologUsing(function($monolog) {
    $monolog->pushHandler(...);

    return $monolog;
});

return $app;
```

### Update-

If u are finding-

> Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::configureMonologUsing()

Then, delete the `vendor/compiled.php` and run `composer update` again.

U will have no problem again !!!!!.

Source-

1. http://laravel.io/forum/03-24-2015-call-to-undefined-method-illuminatefoundationapplicationgetcachedcompilepath
2. https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/runtimeexception-on-fresh-install?page=1

Comment: Thanks Abrar But am getting error when  using configureMonologUsing :  Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Application::configureMonologUsing()

Comment: If u find my answer helpful, please accept it. That will give u and me some points.  Thanks

Comment: Abrar Its not working after composer update . I have also cleared cache and dump autoload .but no success.Thanks

Comment: There is no Compiled.php in my vendor .